# Flutter Firebase fetch.then is not working with initState

Tags: firebase, flutter

I've tried to to fetch data from my firebase realtime database and it worked for antoher app with the same source code. But this time i think something doesn't work with my .then function. I do not receive data for building, but then 5 seconds later there is the data in my console. I know that this is asynchronous and that normally it would work, it shloud build after the init State method. Is there sth i've missed? Thx for help :)

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> _lists = [];

  Future fetchList() async {
    dbRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      print(values);
      _lists.clear();

      values.forEach((key, values) {
        _lists.add(values);
      });

      print(_lists);
    });

    return _lists;
  }

  final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("spieler");
  final dbRefpreise = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("preise");

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchList().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _lists.addAll(value);
      });
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the method but since you cant await and async in iniState youll have to do this.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    getDataList();
    super.initState();
 }

 void getDataList() async {
    await fetchList().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _lists.addAll(value);
      });
    });
}

  Future fetchList() async {
    await dbRef.once()..... //some code
  }
```

Comment: thx but i get the same error :/ when it's buidling my scaffold then there isn't any data yet. IF i run hot reload in vs code then it works because data is then there